# Суффикс ен?

Tags: орфография, морфология

Почему в слове гармоничен суффикс ен?

Comment: Нет там такого суффикса! Сочетание есть, суффикса нет.

Comment: Согласна с Вами. У Тихонова в слове "гармоничный" суффикс -ичн-. В краткой форме появляется беглая гласная Е, но суффикса -не- здесь нет.

Comment: А беглая классная не от суффикса разве?  
Или вы настоцчиво пробиваете только ту идею, что -ен- не суффикс, а часть его? Я не против, хотя исторически, вроде бы там два суффикса.

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы и нет?
Что конкретно непонятно? Откуда Е взялось? Это беглая гласная.
Никаких других причин для непонимания не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

"Гармоничен" - это краткое прилагательное от "гармоничный", в котором есть суффикс "чн". При образовании краткой формы часто появляется вставное "е" для благозвучия: прекрасный-прекрасен, вкусный-вкусен и т.д., то есть суффикс приобретает вид "чен"
     Смущает меня логика Словаря Тихонова, ведь слово образовалось от "гармония", где корень "гармони", значит, суффикс не может содержать в себе "и". Таким образом,получается, что суффикс здесь не "ичн",а "чн", где "ч" - это общеевропейское "к" (garmonic),которое чередуется с "ч" (подобное, например, видно в словах "язык - язычный"). Конечно, я здесь не опираюсь на данные из словарей и исторической грамматики, но cформировавшееся представление о процессах, происходящих в языке, позволяют сделать такой вывод.Возможно, я ошибаюсь, не судите строго.

Comment: "Гармоничный" значит "проникнутый гармонией", прилагательное образовано от слова "гармония" с помощью суффикса -ичн- (Словарь Тихонова). Гласная Е в кратком прилагательном - беглая. Следовательно, суффикса -ен- здесь быть не может. В слове "гармоничен" суффикс -ичен-.

Comment: Смущает меня логика Словаря Тихонова, ведь слово образовалось от "гармония", где корень "гармони", значит, суффикс не может содержать в себе "и". Таким образом,получается, что суффикс здесь не "ичн",а "чн", где "ч" - это общеевропейское "к" (garmonic),которое чередуется с "ч" (подобное, например, видно в словах "язык - язычный"). Конечно, я здесь не опираюсь на данные из словарей и исторической грамматики, но cформировавшееся представление о процессах, происходящих в языке, позволяют сделать такой вывод.Возможно, я ошибаюсь, не судите строго.

Comment: Корень здесь -гармон-, английское -ic (совсем не индоевропейское) - тоже суффикс, но к русскому -ч- никакого отношения не имеет.
Поспорить можно (если очень хочется), только о том, единый ли суффикс -ич(е)н- или составной, из двух.
Язык - язычный - чисто русское чередование, но "к" здесь от корня, это не наш случай. В принципе подобное чередование возсожно и в русских суффиксах (рука - ручка - руче*ч*ка), но это явление другого порядка, связанное не с палатализацией гортанных К-Ч (Г-Ж, Х-С) перед переднерядными гласными, а с диссимиляцией двух рядом стоящих К. Это совсем уж не имеет отношения

Comment: почему английское - не индоевропейское?

Comment: Никак не могу согласиться с тем, что в слове "гармония" корень "гармон-", ведь у существительного не может быть окончания "-ия". Напомню, что так называемое фонетическое окончание здесь "-а", а корень (при транскрипции) -   гармоний-